# Unix and tee — chain of commands

Tags: unix, shell, tee

In a Unix environment, I want to use `tee` on a chain of commands like so:

```
$ echo 1; echo 2 | tee file
1
2

$ cat file
2
```

Why does `file` only end up as having the output from the final command?

For the purposes of this discussion, let's assume I can't break them apart and run the commands separately.

Comment: As well as creating an explicit sub-shell, you can use `{ echo 1; echo 2; } | tee file` to get the output into a file.  Note that `{` has to be separated from the command by a space, and `}` must appear where a command could appear (so it is after the second semicolon).  The other alternative is always to create a new script containing the two indivisible commands and piping the output of that to `tee`: `conjoined-twin-processes | tee file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 ( echo 1; echo 2 ) | tee file
```

Without the parentheses, it's getting parsed as:

```
 echo 1 ; ( echo 2 | tee file )
```

Answer (score 5):

It has only the output of the second command, as the semicolon indicates a new statement to the shell.

Just put them into parentheses:

```
(echo 1; echo 2) | tee file
```